# onchange event on jquery dialogue not working

Tags: jquery-ui

How to handle events on jQuery dialog box. For example I want to handle `onchange` event on jQuery dialog.

Can anyone suggest on the same

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style type="text/css">

label, input {
    display: block;
}
input.text {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 95%;
    padding: .4em;
}
fieldset {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: .6em 0;
}
div#users-contain {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
div#users-contain table {
    margin: 1em 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 150%;
}
div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: .6em 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
    padding: .3em;
}
.validateTips {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
#dialog-form {
    display: none;
}

#button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
     top: 1000px;
}
#buttondisplay {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
     top: 1000px;

}
#buttonadd {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
     top: 1000px;

}

#buttondisplay1 {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
     top: 1000px;

}
#buttonadd1 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
     top: 1000px;

}

#first {
    border: 2px solid;
    top: 500px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #F8F9F9;
    width: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;

}

#firstinfo {
    border: 2px solid;
    top: 29px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #F8F9F9;
    width: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;

}

#headerlogo {

    height: 70px;
    background: #0f2d51;
}
#headerlogo1 {

    height: 70px;
    background: #0f2d51;
}

#centername {

    position: absolute;
     top: 3px;
     padding: 12px;
     font-family: verdana;

}
#centername1 {
    position: absolute;
      font-family: verdana;
     top: 3px;
     padding: 12px;
      right:290px;

}


    </style>   

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myarr=[];
var finalarr=[];
var infopanelarr=[];
var datagridarray=[];
var switchflag=0;
var datapropertyoptions="";
var entitiyoptions ="";
var projectoptions ="";
var moduleoptions ="";
var datapropertyoptions="";
var projects=[];
var modules=[];
var entity=[];
var projectid=0;
var moduleid=0;

function resetpage() {
    location.reload();
    loaddetails();
}

function lowercase(value) {

    var value = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    return value.toLowerCase();

}
function upperCamelCase(value) {

    var valuearr = value.split(" ");

    var val="";

    for(var i =0; i < valuearr.length; i++){
        val = val + capitalFirstLetter(valuearr[i]);
    }

    return val;

}
function lowerCamelCase(value) {

    var valuearr = value.split(" ");

    var val=valuearr[0].toLowerCase();

    for(var i =1; i < valuearr.length; i++){
        val = val + capitalFirstLetter(valuearr[i]);
    }
    //alert(val);
    return val;

}

function capitalFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}


function loaddetails(){

    // getting projects details from service
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        url:  "http://localhost:8081/GetHelpServices/getProjects",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("projects ajax"+JSON.stringify(data));

            for(var j=0; j< data.length; j++){
                projects.push(data[j]);
                projectoptions = projectoptions + "<option>"+data[j].projectName+"</option>";

            }
            document.getElementById('projects').innerHTML = projectoptions;

            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(' Error in processing! '+errorThrown);
        }


    }); 

    // getting modules details from service

     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async:false,
            dataType: "json",
            url:  "http://localhost:8081/GetHelpServices/getModules",
            success: function(data) {

                console.log("modules ajax"+data.length);

                for(var j=0; j< data.length; j++){
                    modules.push(data[j]);
                    moduleoptions = moduleoptions + "<option>"+data[j].moduleName+"</option>";
                }

                document.getElementById('modules').innerHTML = moduleoptions;

                },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(' Error in processing! '+errorThrown);
            }


        }); 



     entity = ["Employee","Student"];


    for(var j=0; j< entity.length; j++){

         entitiyoptions = entitiyoptions + "<option>"+entity[j]+"</option>";
    }


    document.getElementById('entities').innerHTML = entitiyoptions;

  /*  datapropertyoptions = 
      "<option >text</option>" +
      "<option >number</option>" +
      "<option >boolean</option>" +
      "<option >date</option>" +  entitiyoptions + "";



    document.getElementById('dataproperties').innerHTML = datapropertyoptions;  */

}

$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#generateArtifacts").click(function(){

        var cellbl;
        var celdpt;
        var infocelarr=[];




        var infoproject=document.getElementById("mainproject").value;

        var infomodule=document.getElementById("mainmodule").value;

        var infoentity=document.getElementById("mainentity").value;




          for(var k=0; k<modules.length; k++){
              console.log("modules "+modules.length);
              console.log("modules "+modules[k].moduleName);
              console.log("modules "+infomodule);
                if(modules[k].moduleName.trim() == infomodule.trim()){
                    alert(modules[k].moduleId);
                    alert(infomodule);
                    moduleid = modules[k].moduleId;
                }
            }

          for(var k=0; k<projects.length; k++){
              console.log("projects "+projects.length);
              console.log("projects name "+projects[k].projectName);
              console.log("projects read name"+infoproject);
              if(projects[k].projectName.trim() === infoproject.trim()){
                    alert(projects[k].projectId);
                    alert(infoproject);
                    projectid = projects[k].projectId;
                }
          } 

          infoproject = upperCamelCase(infoproject.toLowerCase());
          infomodule = lowercase(infomodule.toLowerCase());
          infoentity = upperCamelCase(infoentity.toLowerCase());

          var dbinfo = {"primaryKey":"Id"};
          console.log(projects);
          var infopanelobj = {'"projectId"': ""+projectid+"", '"projectName"':infoproject, '"moduleId"': ""+moduleid+"", '"moduleName"':infomodule, '"entityName"':infoentity,'"fields"':myarr,'"dbinfo"':dbinfo};
             infopanelarr.push(infopanelobj);
          //finalarr.push({infopanel:infopanelarr});
          console.log(infopanelarr);


        // Posting the data
         $.ajax({
             headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
             },
             type: "POST",
             async:false,
             dataType: "json",

             data : JSON.stringify(infopanelobj),
             url:  "http://localhost:8081/GetHelpServices/insertArtifact",
             success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);


                },
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      console.log(' Error in processing! '+jqXHR);
                      console.log(' Error in processing! '+textStatus);
                 console.log(' Error in processing! '+errorThrown);
             }


         });


    });
    });


$(document).ready(function(){



            var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
                var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();

        var fieldname = dlg.find(("#fieldname")),
            fieldtype = dlg.find(("#fieldtype")),
            fieldtobeassociated = dlg.find(("#fieldtobeassociated")),
            association = dlg.find(("#association")),
            Mandatory = dlg.find(("#Mandatory")),
            Unique = dlg.find(("#Unique"));

                type = type || 'Create';
                var config = {
                    autoOpen: true,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create an account": save_data,
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        dlg.remove();
                    }
                };
                if (type === 'Edit') {
                    config.title = "Edit User";
                   // _.remove(myarr, {"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text()});
                    console.log(myarr);
                    get_data();
                    delete (config.buttons['Create an account']);
                    config.buttons['Edit account'] = function () {
                        row.remove();
                        save_data(); 
                    }; 
                }
                dlg.dialog(config); 
                function get_data() {
                    var _fieldname = $(row.children().get(0)).text();
               // _password = $(row.children().get(2)).text();
                    fieldname.val(_fieldname);
                 //   password.val(_password); 
                } 
                function save_data() {

                    var datatype=fieldtype.find("option:selected").text();

                    if (datatype == "number" || datatype == "text" || datatype == "date" || datatype == "boolean"){
                    var ob ={"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text()};
                    }
                    else {
                    var ob ={"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text(),
                            "fieldToBeDisplayedInDropDown":fieldtobeassociated.find("option:selected").text(),
                            "associationType":association.find("option:selected").text()
                            };  
                    }
                    var temp ={"fieldId":fieldname.val()};

                    var index = _.findIndex(myarr, {"fieldId":fieldname.val()});

                   console.log(type);
                   if (index > -1){
                       myarr.splice(index, 1, ob);

                       $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                       dlg.dialog("close");

                       }
                   else{


                    myarr.push(ob);

                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                    dlg.dialog("close");


                   }



                    console.log(myarr);




                }
            }; 
            $(document).on('click', 'span.delete', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(200, 
        function () {
            // alert($(this).text());
            $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
        }); 
                return false;
            });
            $(document).on('click', 'td a.edit', function () {
                new_dialog('Edit', $(this).parents('tr'));
                return false;
            }); 
            $("#create-user").button().click(new_dialog); 

        });






    </script>
<body onload="loaddetails()">


<div class="container" >
  <h2>UI Details</h2>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">


      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 <label for="inputdefault">Project</label>
                   <input class="form-control"  list="projects"  id="mainproject" name="project">
                      <datalist id="projects">
                      </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="inputdefault">Module</label>
                 <input class="form-control"  list="modules" id="mainmodule" name="module">
                  <datalist id="modules">
                  </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label for="inputlg">Entity</label>
              <input class="form-control"  list="entities" id="mainentity" name="module">
                  <datalist id="entities">
                  </datalist>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>




   <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>       
            <form>
        <fieldset>

            <label for="fieldname">
                Field Name*</label>
            <input class="form-control "  type="text" name="fieldname" id="fieldname" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <br>
            <label for="fieldtype">
                Type*</label>
            <select class="form-control " id="fieldtype" >
                <option value="1">text</option>
                <option value="2">boolean</option>
                <option value="3">number</option>
                <option value="4">date</option>
                <option value="4">Student</option>
            </select>

           <br>
           <label for="fieldtobeassociated">
                Field to be associated</label>
            <select class="form-control " id="fieldtobeassociated" >
                <option value="1">name</option>
                <option value="2">address</option>
            </select> 

          <br>
          <label for="association">
                Association Type</label>
           <select class="form-control " id="association" >
                <option value="1">Foreign Key</option>
                <option value="2">One-to-One</option>
                <option value="2">One-to-Many</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-One</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-Many</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-Many+Joint Tables</option>
            </select> 

         <br>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="Mandatory" id="Mandatory">Mandatory</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="Unique" id="Unique">Unique</label>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

     <div class="container" >
    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h2>Fields</h2>

             <button id="create-user">
        Add Fields</button>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th>Field Name </th>
                    <th>Type</th>

                    <th> Update</th>
                    <th> Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success " id="generateArtifacts">Generate Artifacts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger " onclick="resetpage()">Reset Artifacts</a>

        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, I want to hide/show `div` on jQuery dialog on click `onchange` event on the same dialog's `select option` element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There is too much to your example, that it's difficult to assist.

Comment: I also see that you load jQuery 3.2.1 and then jQuery 1.8.3, this will cause some conflicts and may cause your scripts to not run as expected. You should only load one of the two, I would advise the 3.2.1.

Comment: Thank you. I removed old version 1.8.3 and modified my code in different . finally it worked.

Comment: Moved this to an answer if you feel like marking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you will want to ensure you are only loading jQuery 3.2.1 and not both.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just refined my answer and posting below. the below code working properly with my expected requirement. But need some suggestion on reading table outerHTML data.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myarr = [];
    var finalarr = [];
    var infopanelarr = [];
    var datagridarray = [];
    var switchflag = 0;
    var datapropertyoptions = "";
    var entitiyoptions = "";
    var projectoptions = "";
    var moduleoptions = "";
    var datapropertyoptions = "";
    var projects = [];
    var modules = [];
    var entity = [];
    var projectid = 0;
    var moduleid = 0;
    var flag=true;

    function resetpage() {
        location.reload();
        loaddetails();
    }

    function lowercase(value) {

        var value = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');

        return value.toLowerCase();

    }
    function upperCamelCase(value) {

        var valuearr = value.split(" ");

        var val = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < valuearr.length; i++) {
            val = val + capitalFirstLetter(valuearr[i]);
        }

        return val;

    }
    function lowerCamelCase(value) {

        var valuearr = value.split(" ");

        var val = valuearr[0].toLowerCase();

        for (var i = 1; i < valuearr.length; i++) {
            val = val + capitalFirstLetter(valuearr[i]);
        }
        //alert(val);
        return val;

    }

    function capitalFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    function loaddetails(){

    }

    function isPrimitive(datatype){

           if (datatype == "text" || datatype == "number" || datatype == "date" || datatype == "boolean"){

               flag = true; 

            }
            else {
              flag=false;

            }

           return flag;
    }

    function onFieldTypeChange(){
        var entityoptions = "";
        var element = document.getElementById("fieldtype").value;
        if (isPrimitive(element)){
            //alert('hi');
            entityoptions = "<option>id</option><option>name</option><option>address</option>";
            $('#entityProperties').hide();
        }
        else {
            entityoptions = "<option value='111'>Student</option><option value='112'>Employee</option><option value='113'>Address</option>";
            $('#entityProperties').show();
        }

        document.getElementById("fieldtobeassociated").innerHTML = entityoptions;
    }

    function insert_save_row(){

        var fieldname=document.getElementById("fieldname").value;
        var fieldtype=document.getElementById("fieldtype").value;

         var table=document.getElementById("fields");
         var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
         var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr class='item' id='row"+table_len+"'><td class='theCell' id='fieldname"+table_len+"'>"+fieldname+"</td><td class='theCell' id='fieldtype"+table_len+"'>"+fieldtype+"</td><td><input type='button' class='btn btn-success'  id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'></td><td> <input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

         document.getElementById("save").style.display="block";
         document.getElementById("edit").style.display="none";
         //alert(fieldtype);

         if (isPrimitive(fieldtype))
             $('#entityProperties').hide();
         else
             $('#entityProperties').show();

         $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    }

    function edit_row(no)
    {

     var name=document.getElementById("fieldname"+no);
     var type=document.getElementById("fieldtype"+no);

     var vname = name.innerHTML;
     var vtype = type.innerHTML;

     document.getElementById("temp_row_no").value   = no;
     document.getElementById("fieldname").value = vname;
     document.getElementById("fieldtype").value = vtype;
     document.getElementById("save").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("edit").style.display="block";

     if (isPrimitive(vtype.trim()))
         $('#entityProperties').hide();
     else
         $('#entityProperties').show();

     $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }

    function delete_row(no)
    {
     document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
    }

    function edit_save_row()
    {
         var no = document.getElementById("temp_row_no").value;
         var name=document.getElementById("fieldname").value;
         var type=document.getElementById("fieldtype").value;
         document.getElementById("fieldname"+no).innerHTML=name;
         document.getElementById("fieldtype"+no).innerHTML=type;    

         if (isPrimitive(type))
             $('#entityProperties').hide();
         else
             $('#entityProperties').show();

         $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    }
    function addField(){

         document.getElementById("save").style.display="block";
         document.getElementById("edit").style.display="none";
         document.getElementById("fieldname").value = "";
         document.getElementById("fieldtype").value ="";

          $('#entityProperties').hide();

          $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var  cellbl, celdpt, infocelarr=[];
     $("#generateArtifacts").click(function(){

         var x = document.getElementById("fields").rows.length;

         alert(document.getElementById("fields").tBodies.item(0).innerHTML);

         var table = document.getElementById("fields");
         for (var i = 3, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
              alert(i+"--"+cell);
         }



            var projectid = document.getElementById("mainproject").value

            var infoproject=document.getElementById("mainproject").text;

            var infomodule=document.getElementById("mainmodule").value;

            var infoentity=document.getElementById("mainentity").value;

           /* infoproject = upperCamelCase(infoproject.toLowerCase());
           infomodule = lowercase(infomodule.toLowerCase());
           infoentity = upperCamelCase(infoentity.toLowerCase()); */

             var dbinfo = {"primaryKey":"Id"};

             var infopanelobj = {'"projectId"': ""+projectid+"", '"projectName"':infoproject, '"moduleId"': ""+moduleid+"", '"moduleName"':infomodule, '"entityName"':infoentity,'"fields"':infocelarr,'"dbinfo"':dbinfo};

        console.log(infopanelobj);

     });
    });


</script>
<body >

    <div class="container">
        <h2>UI Details</h2>

        <form>
            <div class="form-group">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputdefault">Project</label> 
                        <input class="form-control" list="projects" id="mainproject" name="project">
                        <datalist id="projects"> <option value="Chrome"></option></datalist>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputdefault">Module</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" list="modules" id="mainmodule" name="module">
                        <datalist id="modules"><option value="Chrome"></option></datalist>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputlg">Entity</label> <input class="form-control"
                            list="entities" id="mainentity" name="module">
                        <datalist id="entities"><option value="Chrome"></option> </datalist>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Field Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label for="fieldname"> Field Name*</label> <input
                        class="form-control " type="text" name="fieldname" id="fieldname"
                        value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> <br>
                    <label for="fieldtype2"> Type*</label> 
                        <input class="form-control" list="fieldtypelist" id="fieldtype" onchange="onFieldTypeChange()">
                        <datalist id="fieldtypelist"><option >text</option><option >number</option><option >date</option></datalist>



                <div id="entityProperties">
                      <br/><label for="fieldtobeassociated"> Field to be
                        associated</label> <select class="form-control " id="fieldtobeassociated">

                    </select> <br> <label for="association"> Association Type</label> <select
                        class="form-control " id="association">
                        <option value="1">Foreign Key</option>
                        <option value="2">One-to-One</option>
                        <option value="2">One-to-Many</option>
                        <option value="2">Many-to-One</option>
                        <option value="2">Many-to-Many</option>
                        <option value="2">Many-to-Many+Joint Tables</option>
                    </select> <br>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Mandatory"
                            id="Mandatory">Mandatory</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Unique" id="Unique">Unique</label>
                    </div>

               </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="insert_save_row()">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="edit_save_row()" style="display:none">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

            <h2>Fields</h2>

            <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="addField()">Launch
                Demo Modal</a>
                <br/><br/><br/>
            <table id="fields" class="table table-striped"">
                <thead class="thead-default">
                    <tr >
                        <th>Field Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>

                        <th>Update</th>
                        <th>Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="rows">
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" " id="generateArtifacts">Generate
            Artifacts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="resetpage()">Reset
            Artifacts</a>
         <input id="temp_row_no" style="display:none"></input>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am adding data to table outerHMTL in javascript. How to read its table contents. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified my code in different way. Initially my problem is that i am unable to populate data for second dropdown onchange event of first dropdown on same jquery ui dialog. I have used jquery ui dialog's clone() method. somehow it did't work. But After cleaning up code and adding different versions of jquery, able to generate another dialog on top of existing dialog box and able to set the data properly.

```
var nestedfiled="";
var nestedassociation="";
var flag=true;


$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#dialog-form1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function(){

                var ftb = $( "#dialog-form1");
                var kk= ftb.find("#fieldtobeassociated");
                var bb= ftb.find("#association");
                nestedfiled = kk.find("option:selected").text();
                nestedassociation = bb.find("option:selected").text();
                flag=false;
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },

            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

            var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
                var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
                nestedfiled = "" ;
                nestedassociation = "";
        var fieldname = dlg.find(("#fieldname")),
            fieldtype = dlg.find(("#fieldtype")),
            fieldtobeassociated = dlg.find(("#fieldtobeassociated")),
            association = dlg.find(("#association")),
            Mandatory = dlg.find(("#Mandatory")),
            Unique = dlg.find(("#Unique"));

                type = type || 'Create';
                var config = {
                    autoOpen: true,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create an account": save_data,
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        dlg.remove();
                    }
                };
                if (type === 'Edit') {
                    config.title = "Edit User";
                   // _.remove(myarr, {"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text()});
                    console.log(myarr);
                    get_data();
                    delete (config.buttons['Create an account']);
                    config.buttons['Edit account'] = function () {
                        row.remove();
                        save_data(); 
                    }; 
                }
                dlg.dialog(config); 
                function get_data() {
                    var _fieldname = $(row.children().get(0)).text();
               // _password = $(row.children().get(2)).text();
                    fieldname.val(_fieldname);
                 //   password.val(_password); 
                } 
                function save_data() {



                    var datatype=fieldtype.find("option:selected").text();

                 if (datatype == "number" || datatype == "text" || datatype == "date" || datatype == "boolean") {

                    var ob ={"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text()};

                    var temp ={"fieldId":fieldname.val()};

                    var index = _.findIndex(myarr, {"fieldId":fieldname.val()});

                   console.log(type);
                   if (index > -1){
                       myarr.splice(index, 1, ob);

                       $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                       dlg.dialog("close");

                       }
                   else{


                    myarr.push(ob);

                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");

                     dlg.dialog("close");


                   }

                    }
                    else {

                        flag=true;

                    $( "#dialog-form1").find(("#fieldtobeassociated")).empty();
                    $( "#dialog-form1").find(("#fieldtobeassociated")).append("<option>12</option><option>13</option>");
                    /* .data('param_1', 'whateverdata') */

                    if(nestedfiled == ""  && nestedassociation == "")
                    $( "#dialog-form1").dialog("open");

                    var ob ={"fieldId":fieldname.val(),"type":fieldtype.find("option:selected").text(),
                            "fieldToBeDisplayedInDropDown":nestedfiled,
                            "associationType":nestedassociation
                            };  

                    var index = _.findIndex(myarr, {"fieldId":fieldname.val()});

                    console.log(type);
                    if (index > -1){
                       myarr.splice(index, 1, ob);

                       if(nestedfiled !== ""  && nestedassociation !== "")
                       $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                        dlg.dialog("close");

                       }
                    else{


                     myarr.push(ob);
                     if(nestedfiled !== ""  && nestedassociation !== "")
                     $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + fieldname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + (fieldtype.find("option:selected").text() + ' ') + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");

                     //dlg.dialog("close");


                    }

                    }




                    console.log(myarr);




                }
            }; 



            $(document).on('click', 'span.delete', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(200, 
        function () {
            // alert($(this).text());
            $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
        }); 
                return false;
            });
            $(document).on('click', 'td a.edit', function () {
                new_dialog('Edit', $(this).parents('tr'));
                return false;
            }); 
            $("#create-user").button().click(new_dialog); 


        });







    </script>
<body onload="loaddetails()">


<div class="container" >
  <h2>UI Details</h2>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">


      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 <label for="inputdefault">Project</label>
                   <input class="form-control"  list="projects"  id="mainproject" name="project">
                      <datalist id="projects">
                      </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="inputdefault">Module</label>
                 <input class="form-control"  list="modules" id="mainmodule" name="module">
                  <datalist id="modules">
                  </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label for="inputlg">Entity</label>
              <input class="form-control"  list="entities" id="mainentity" name="module">
                  <datalist id="entities">
                  </datalist>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>




   <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>       
            <form>
        <fieldset>

            <label for="fieldname">
                Field Name*</label>
            <input class="form-control "  type="text" name="fieldname" id="fieldname" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <br>
            <label for="fieldtype2">
                Type*</label>
            <select class="form-control " id="fieldtype" >
                <option value="1">text</option>
                <option value="2">boolean</option>
                <option value="3">number</option>
                <option value="4">date</option>
                <option value="4">Student</option>
                <option value="4">Employee</option>
            </select>


        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="dialog-form1" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>       
            <form>
        <fieldset>



           <br>
           <label for="fieldtobeassociated">
                Field to be associated</label>
            <select class="form-control " id="fieldtobeassociated" >

            </select> 

          <br>
          <label for="association">
                Association Type</label>
           <select class="form-control " id="association" >
                <option value="1">Foreign Key</option>
                <option value="2">One-to-One</option>
                <option value="2">One-to-Many</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-One</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-Many</option>
                <option value="2">Many-to-Many+Joint Tables</option>
            </select> 

         <br>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="Mandatory" id="Mandatory">Mandatory</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="Unique" id="Unique">Unique</label>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

     <div class="container" >
    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h2>Fields</h2>

             <button id="create-user">
        Add Fields</button>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th>Field Name </th>
                    <th>Type</th>

                    <th> Update</th>
                    <th> Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success " id="generateArtifacts">Generate Artifacts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger " onclick="resetpage()">Reset Artifacts</a>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for suggestions.